# TPIL 3.6: example : ¬(p → q) → p ∧ ¬q

Tags: lean

[Section 3.6](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/propositions_and_proofs.html#examples-of-propositional-validities) of Theorem Proving in Lean shows the following:

```
example : ¬(p → q) → p ∧ ¬q
```

Let's rewrite the `¬` expressions in terms of `→`:

```
example : ((p → q) → false) → p ∧ (q → false)
```

At this point, it's clear that we'll have a parameter of type `(p → q) → false`:

```
example : ((p → q) → false) → p ∧ (q → false) := 

    (assume hpqf : (p → q) → false,

        ...)
```

The text mentions that this one will require classical reasoning. So let's assume we'll have to use `em`.

## Approach 1

```
example : ((p → q) → false) → p ∧ (q → false) := 

    (assume hpqf : (p → q) → false,

        or.elim (em p)

            (assume hp : p,
                and.intro
                    hp 
                    (assume hq : q, hpqf (λ hp' : p, hq)))

            (assume hpf : p → false,

                and.intro 

                    -- Need to return a value of type p here.
                    -- Or a false (and use with false.elim).

                    (assume hq : q, hpqf (λ hp : p, hq))))
```

As mentioned in the comment, we'd need a value of type `p` or a `false`. It isn't clear how to get these at that point.

Let's try another approach.

## Approach 2

```
example : ((p → q) → false) → p ∧ (q → false) := 

    (assume hpqf : (p → q) → false,

        or.elim (em q)

            (assume hq : q,
                false.elim (hpqf (λ hp : p, hq)))

            (assume hqf : q → false,

                or.elim (em p)

                    (assume hp : p, and.intro hp hqf)

                    (assume hpf : p → false,

                        -- and.intro ...
                        -- Here we have no access to p or q. It seems we'd need to generate false?
                    )))
```

Similar situation. Let's try to start with `and.intro` first and use `em` inside its "branches":

## Approach 3

```
example : ((p → q) → false) → p ∧ (q → false) := 

    (assume hpqf : (p → q) → false,

        and.intro

            or.elim (em p)

                (assume hp : p, hp)

                (assume hpf : p → false,
                    -- Need to generate a 'p' here.

                    -- Or a false.

                )

            or.elim (em q)

                (assume hq : q,
                    (λ hq': q, hpqf (assume hp : p, hq)))

                (assume hqf : q → false, hqf))
```

Similar outcome.

Should I use an entirely different approach? Section 3.5 mentions `by_cases` and `by_contradiction`; would one of those be useful here?

Thanks for any suggestions!

---

**UPDATE**

Here's an answer based on Kevin's approach described below:

```
example : ((p → q) → false) → p ∧ (q → false) := 

    (assume hpqf : (p → q) → false,

        by_cases

            (assume hp : p,

                by_cases

                    (assume hq : q, and.intro hp (λ hq' : q, hpqf (λ hp' : p, hq)))

                    (assume hqf : q → false, and.intro hp hqf))

            (assume hpf : p → false,

                by_cases

                    (assume hq : q, false.elim (hpqf (λ hp : p, hq)))

                    (assume hqf : q → false,

                        false.elim (hpqf (λ hp : p, false.elim (hpf hp))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

`by_cases` gives you access to "proof by truth tables". In other words, we can prove `¬(p → q) → p ∧ ¬q` just by checking it's true in the four cases (`p` and `q` true, `p` true but `q` false, ...).

```
variables (p q : Prop)
open classical
example : ¬(p → q) → p ∧ ¬q :=
λ h, by_cases
  (assume hp : p, 
    by_cases
    (assume hq : q, _)
    (assume hnq : ¬ q, _) 
  )
  (assume hnp : ¬ p, 
    by_cases
    ( assume hq : q, _)
    (assume hnq : ¬ q, _)
  )
```

Here I didn't fill in the four `_` arguments, but putting your cursor on each one will show you the local context. I don't want to fill them in because this super-verbose term mode drives me nuts.

In tactic mode (introduced in chapter 5) you can spell it out in full like this:

```
import tactic.interactive

variables (p q : Prop)
open classical
example : ¬(p → q) → p ∧ ¬q :=
begin
  intro hnpq,
  classical,
  by_cases hp : p; by_cases hq : q; split;
  -- 8 goals (replace previous semicolon by a comma to see this)
  try {assumption}, -- four left
  { intro h, apply hnpq, intro h', assumption},
  { exfalso, apply hnpq, intro h, assumption},
  { intro h, apply hnpq, intro h', assumption},
  { exfalso, apply hnpq, intro h', exfalso, apply hp, assumption}
end
```

but in reality I'd just do this:

```
import tactic.tauto
variables (p q : Prop)
example : ¬(p → q) → p ∧ ¬q := by tauto!
```

You can [try all this online](https://leanprover-community.github.io/lean-web-editor/#code=import%20tactic.tauto%0Avariables%20%28p%20q%20%3A%20Prop%29%0Aexample%20%3A%20%C2%AC%28p%20%E2%86%92%20q%29%20%E2%86%92%20p%20%E2%88%A7%20%C2%ACq%20%3A%3D%20by%20tauto!) without even having to install Lean.

Comment: Thanks Kevin! I've updated the question to show an answer based on your suggestion.

Comment: One can look explicitly at the proof which `tauto!` found using `def XYZ : ¬(p → q) → p ∧ ¬q := by tauto!` and then `#print XYZ`; one then discovers that if you import `logic.basic` then your exact result is `not_imp.mp`